# Get Capybara's active 'within's?

Tags: capybara, rspec-rails

Several `shared_examples_for` and/or proc stack frames deep, can I get all of the "active" `within` selectors set along the way (*e.g.*, for inclusion in a custom `expect` message) by some means more more elegant than passing/adding them through the call chain as tramp data?

I see [Capybara::Session](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Session)'s `within` variants for setting & executing within, but nothing that seems to report/query them.